# Switch Button Implementation

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm working on converting the value from an unit conversion to another using switch button.

Meaning to say, I will input all necessary parameters for the calculation. Upon choosing the option from the switch button, it will output according to unit chosen by user after I initiated the calculation by clicking on the "Calculate" button only.

However, the current problem I'm facing is even without clicking on the "Calculate" button, I was able to perform the calculation using the switch button too.

I know that my problem shall lies on the following lines of code.

```
double result = 0;
        if (v == calButton) {
            double lamda = 300000000 / freq;

            result = tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI * distance), 2) / light / 100;
            //double radius = 5000;
            ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(result));

            final double finalResult = result;
            Switch select_unit=(Switch)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            select_unit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(finalResult));
                    } else {
                        ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(10 * Math.log10(finalResult * 1000)));
                    }
                }
            });
```

From the code above, obviously the problem came because I implemented both the "Calculate" & "Switch" button in the same method. I tried to separate the OnCheckChanged method out of it. However was greeted with errors. As example, it states that the variable result is never used.

Can someone provide some guides/hints?

**This is my interface:**

[image]

**My full code:**

```
package com.epsilon.rfcalculator.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epsilon.rfcalculator.R;

public class FreeSpaceActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    EditText tPowerEdit = null;
    EditText tGainEdit = null;
    EditText rGainEdit = null;
    EditText freqEdit = null;
    EditText distanceEdit = null;
    EditText lightEdit = null;
    Button calButton = null;
    Button graphButton = null;
    Button clearButton = null;
    Button plotButton = null;
    Switch switchButton=null;

    EditText radEdit = null;//testing

    private ScrollView llLayout;
    private FragmentActivity faActivity;
    //private Switch switch1;

    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        faActivity = (FragmentActivity) this.getActivity();
        llLayout = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_free_space, container, false);

        tPowerEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        rGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        freqEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        distanceEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        lightEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        calButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        graphButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        graphButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        plotButton =(Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.plot_button);
        plotButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        radEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28);//testing



        return llLayout;
    }

    /*private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return null;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String tPowerStr = tPowerEdit.getText().toString();
        String tGainStr = tGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String rGainStr = rGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();
        String distanceStr = distanceEdit.getText().toString();
        String lightStr = lightEdit.getText().toString();
        double tPower = Double.parseDouble(!tPowerStr.isEmpty() ? tPowerStr : "0");
        double tGain = Double.parseDouble(!tGainStr.isEmpty() ? tGainStr : "0");
        double rGain = Double.parseDouble(!rGainStr.isEmpty() ? rGainStr : "0");
        double freq = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");
        double distance = Double.parseDouble(!distanceStr.isEmpty() ? distanceStr : "0");
        double light = Double.parseDouble(!lightStr.isEmpty() ? lightStr : "0");

        String radStr = radEdit.getText().toString();//testing
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(!radStr.isEmpty() ? radStr : "0");//testing


        double result = 0;
        if (v == calButton) {
            double lamda = 300000000 / freq;

            result = tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI * distance), 2) / light / 100;
            //double radius = 5000;
            //((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(result));

            final double finalResult = result;
            Switch select_unit=(Switch)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            select_unit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(finalResult));
                    } else {
                        ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(Double.toString(10 * Math.log10(finalResult * 1000)));
                    }
                }
            });



        }
        else if (v == graphButton) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GraphActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("model", "freeSpace");
            intent.putExtra("tp", tPower);
            intent.putExtra("tg", tGain);
            intent.putExtra("rg", rGain);
            intent.putExtra("f", freq);
            intent.putExtra("l", light);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v == clearButton) {
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28)).setText("");
            ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText("");
            //((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpacePrd)).setText("");
        } else if (v == plotButton) {
            //double radius = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putDouble("radius", result);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code like that:

```
public class FreeSpaceActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    EditText tPowerEdit = null;
    EditText tGainEdit = null;
    EditText rGainEdit = null;
    EditText freqEdit = null;
    EditText distanceEdit = null;
    EditText lightEdit = null;
    Button calButton = null;
    Button graphButton = null;
    Button clearButton = null;
    Button plotButton = null;
    Switch switchButton=null;

    EditText radEdit = null;//testing

    private ScrollView llLayout;
    private FragmentActivity faActivity;
    //private Switch switch1;
    // Changes here
    private double mResult = 0;
    private Switch mSelectUnit;
    private TextView mTextFreeSpaces;
    private boolean mIsCalculated;// flag to show the result only when you click on calculate button


    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        faActivity = (FragmentActivity) this.getActivity();
        llLayout = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_free_space, container, false);

        tPowerEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        rGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        freqEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        distanceEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        lightEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        calButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        graphButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        graphButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        plotButton =(Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.plot_button);
        plotButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        radEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28);//testing

        // Changes here
        mTextFreeSpaces = (TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)

        mSelectUnit =(Switch)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        mSelectUnit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    updateFreeSpacesText(isChecked);
                }
            });
        return llLayout;
    }

    /*private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return null;
    }*/

    private void updateFreeSpacesText(boolean isSwitcherChecked) {
        if(mIsCalculated){
           if(isSwitcherChecked){
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText(Double.toString(mResult));
           } else {
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText(Double.toString(10 * Math.log10(mResult* 1000)));
           }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String tPowerStr = tPowerEdit.getText().toString();
        String tGainStr = tGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String rGainStr = rGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();
        String distanceStr = distanceEdit.getText().toString();
        String lightStr = lightEdit.getText().toString();
        double tPower = Double.parseDouble(!tPowerStr.isEmpty() ? tPowerStr : "0");
        double tGain = Double.parseDouble(!tGainStr.isEmpty() ? tGainStr : "0");
        double rGain = Double.parseDouble(!rGainStr.isEmpty() ? rGainStr : "0");
        double freq = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");
        double distance = Double.parseDouble(!distanceStr.isEmpty() ? distanceStr : "0");
        double light = Double.parseDouble(!lightStr.isEmpty() ? lightStr : "0");

        String radStr = radEdit.getText().toString();//testing
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(!radStr.isEmpty() ? radStr : "0");//testing


        if (v == calButton) {
            double lamda = 300000000 / freq;

            mResult = tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI * distance), 2) / light / 100;
          mIsCalculated = true;
          updateFreeSpacesText(mSelectUnit.isChecked());


        }
        else if (v == graphButton) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GraphActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("model", "freeSpace");
            intent.putExtra("tp", tPower);
            intent.putExtra("tg", tGain);
            intent.putExtra("rg", rGain);
            intent.putExtra("f", freq);
            intent.putExtra("l", light);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v == clearButton) {
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8)).setText("");
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28)).setText("");
            ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText("");
            //((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpacePrd)).setText("");
        } else if (v == plotButton) {
            //double radius = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putDouble("radius", result);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }



}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have this issue where if I were to switch the button. For example, the default unit is W and I would like to switch to dbm, it automatically outputs the answer without the need of clicking the "Calculate" button.

Comment: I've updated my answer...  i've added a flag to block updating the TextView before clicking to calculate Button.

Comment: Have you tried my edited answer? otherwise, if you want to update the TextView only when you click to Calculate Button, you can just remove the "setOnCheckedChangeListener()" from the Switcher.

Comment: Huh? may I know what changes that you have made? I can't see any diffference ><. Thanks

Comment: Testing now. Sorry :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been trying. Just another question, I notice that after second trying, it can still calculate the answer from the switch button.

For example, on 1st attempt. Upon inputting all the parameters. It wouldn't display any outputs till I click the  "Calculate" button. However, when comes to second attempt, it can display the answer again when I was playing with the switching button. Is this normal because I did not exit the activity?

Comment: Is there any way to "reset" without exiting the activity?

Comment: You can add a TextWatcher to your EditTexts, so when the user change the input you reset the previous result.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to TextWatcher so I did some googles. There was few posts telling us to perform Edittext.setText("") in one of the method for the TextChangedListener. Isn't the same on my "Clear" button? Btw, does the TextWatcher work on Edittext fields only? Because I think i just have to reset my mResult field which isn't the same as Edittext fields.

Comment: Hi again, I just tried a new method which is by implementing following code. "super.onCreate(null);" which would not save or ignore the savedInstance.

Answer (score 0):

You've stuffed everything inside the onClick(View v) method. Are you sure about it? This event will be fired every time no matter where you tap on the screen. Don't do it unless you require it. Do it individually for each control according to your requirement within the onCreateView method. You've implemented interface for switch button within the implementation of calculate button. Separate them and save the state of the switch button in some global variable. Access the global variable within the calculate button listener. Hope it helps!! All the best